# Parse XML request in Swift

Tags: xml, swift, swxmlhash

I am just beginning to dabble around with Swift.

I have the following get request using NSURLSession:

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://api.bart.gov/api/sched.aspx?cmd=arrive&orig=24th&dest=rock&key=MW9S-E7SL-26DU-VV8V")

let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) {(data, response, error) in

        println(NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))

          }

    task.resume()
```

However, the data is all jumbled up in XML. How do I go about formatting the data in a readable manner?

I am trying to parse the data using this line of code:

```
let xml = SWXMLHash.parse(data: data)
```

However, this is giving me an error about not being able to use `data`. Am I headed in the right direction with the SWXMLHash.Parse function?

Comment: You should look into SwiftyJSON for serializing your JSON response.

Comment: @pbush25 This is what I have so far:

            let json = JSON(NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)))

However, it is not compiling. Any idea?

Comment: Or `NSJSONSerialization`. But `SWXMLHash` sounds like it's an XML parser, and XML is a completely different thing. Do you have JSON or XML?

Comment: @Rob Ahh. Oops! I actually need XML, not JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for the `parse` method is without `data:` label:

```
let xml = SWXMLHash.parse(data)
```

Comment: Hi @Rob can you say where should I put the "let xml = SWXMLHash.parse(data)" code ? because i'm stuck in using SWXMLHash to parse xml url

Comment: @anonymox Presumably inside your `dataTaskWithURL` completion block (after, of course, you've confirmed that `data` is not `nil`).

Comment: but it's not parsing the xml data, I don't get any result. this is my code : i appreciate your help,  
                   
let url = NSURL(string: "http://razavitv.aqr.ir/index/rss/2")

let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) {(data, response, error) in
    
    var xml = SWXMLHash.parse(data!)
    let count = xml["channel"].all.count
    
    
}

task.resume()

Comment: I'd suggest you post your own question, as we're beyond the scope of what we can easily diagnose here. In your question, include a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I've created my question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34586266/not-getting-any-result-parsing-xml-using-swxmlhash